# Java - Mysql - Multiple query

Tags: java, mysql, multi-query

String qLink = "";

```
                        qLink = "INSERT INTO trackgps.queclinklogs(Supplier,NtwProtocol,IMEI,log,DBTIME)" +
                                "VALUES"                    +
                                "("                         +
                                "'" + supplier              + "',"+
                                "'" + protocol              + "',"+
                                "'" + failedQIMEI           + "',"+
                                "'" + failedQLog            + "',"+
                                "'" + currentQuecTimestamp  + "'" +
                                "),"                        +
                                "("                         +
                                "'" + supplier              + "'" + "," +
                                "'" + protocol              + "'" + "," +
                                "'" + QuecLinkIMEI          + "'" + "," +
                                "'" + data2                 + "'" + "," +
                                "'" + currentQuecTimestamp  + "'" +
                                ")";    


                        Statement stmtLink = connQ.createStatement();
                        stmtLink.execute(qLink);
                        stmtLink.close();
```

String bytesconsumption = "";

```
                    bytesconsumption = "INSERT INTO test_backoffice.carrierDataConsumption(IMEI,beginMonth,endMonth,dataConsumed,month,year) VALUES"    +
                                        "("                                                                                                             +
                                        "'"+ QuecLinkIMEI                                                                                   + "'" + "," +
                                        "NOW()"                                                                                                   + "," +
                                        "NOW()"                                                                                                   + "," +
                                        "'"+ totalBytesConsumed                                                                                  + "'," +
                                        "MONTH(NOW())"                                                                                            + "," +
                                        "YEAR(NOW())"                                                                                                   +
                                        ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE endMonth = NOW(), dataConsumed = dataConsumed + " + totalBytesConsumed;

                    Statement stmtbytesconsumption;

                    stmtbytesconsumption = connQ.createStatement();
                    stmtbytesconsumption.execute(bytesconsumption);
                    stmtbytesconsumption.close();
```

String qdebug = "";

```
    qdebug = "INSERT INTO trackgps.rawdata(Module,SubModule,IMEI,listenerTime,msg)" +
            "VALUES"                    +
            "("                         +
            "'"+ "LISTENER TCP"         + "'" + "," +
            "'"+ SubMod                 + "'" + "," +
            "'"+ identifier             + "'" + "," +
            "'"+ listendatetime         + "'" + "," +
            "'"+ msg                    + "'" +
            ")";    

    Statement stmtqdebug = conn.createStatement();
    stmtqdebug.execute(qdebug);
    stmtqdebug.close();
```

Is there anyway to execute this three inserts in just one java statement?
Instead of creating 3 Statements with 3 executes and 3 closes?

Other question I have, Should I use Statements or PrepareStatements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call all 3 queries on one statement:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(qLink);
stmt.executeUpdate(bytesconsumption);
stmt.executeUpdate(qdebug);
stmt.close();
```

Use `PreparedSatement` instead of `Statement` when you want:

- to execute the same statement many times with different set of parameters
- don't take care about parameter formating, eg. if `listendatetime` is of type Timestamp, you can use just `ps.setTimestamp(4, listendatetime)` and a driver formats it properly independently on underlaying database.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the queries with a ";" character to split it and execute all in a unique statement.

The query:

```
"INSERT INTO table1 ... ;INSERT INTO table2 ...;"
```

and the execution:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("INSERT INTO table1 ... ;INSERT INTO table2 ...;");
st.close();
```

Cheers

Comment: tks :). I'm going to try it.

Comment: it doesn't work :(. It only works when I do separate prepared statement.

Comment: You can use @agad solution! :)

Comment: Tk u @fastebro. I will use it :)