# I am try to insert data in mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1064

I want to insert data in 2 table with single query. bt it gives error

mycode is shown below.

```
public class Trains extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        int tid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tid"));
        String tname=request.getParameter("tname");
        String ttype=request.getParameter("ttype");
        String stncode=request.getParameter("stn_code");
        String stnname=request.getParameter("stn_name");
        String availtime=request.getParameter("Avail_time");
        String depttime=request.getParameter("Dep_time");
        String halttime=request.getParameter("Halt_time");
        String dist=request.getParameter("distance");

        String[] avail_day=request.getParameterValues("week");

        try {
            String query="INSERT INTO Train_info(Train_ID,Train_Name,Train_Type,Runs_On) values(?,?,?,?); INSERT INTO Train_route(stn_code,stn_name,arrival_time,Destn_time,Halt_time,Distance) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Railway","root","mysql123");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query);

            ps.setInt(1, tid);
            ps.setString(2, tname);
            ps.setString(3, ttype);
            ps.setString(4, stncode);
            ps.setString(5, stnname);
            ps.setString(6, availtime);
            ps.setString(7, depttime);
            ps.setString(8, halttime);
            ps.setString(9, dist);
            for(int i=0;i<avail_day.length;i++){
            ps.setString(10, avail_day[i]);
            }

            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                out.println("Successfully Registration");
                response.sendRedirect("TrainRoute.jsp");
            }
            else{
                out.println("Registration failed");
                response.sendRedirect("Error.java");
            }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

error is:-

> java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Train_route(stn_code,stn_name,arrival_time,Destn_time,Halt_time,Dist' at line 1

Comment: You can not insert into 2 tables at once

Comment: `ps.setString(10, avail_day[i]);` ... this makes no sense to keep assiging a different value to the tenth parameter

Comment: You _can_ do two inserts in a single transaction, but not in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

See this: [Java - Mysql - Multiple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782852/java-mysql-multiple-query)

The `INSERT INTO` your syntax error message calls out the *second* insert in your `query` string.  The MySQL JDBC driver, like most MySQL drivers, only accepts one query per call to `Connection.preparedStatement()` call.

You'll need to refactor your code to use two prepared statements, once for each table.

If you're used to working with other makes and model of SQL table servers, this restriction can trip you up.